# Refreshing JWT token - Do it? When?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, react-native, jwt

I have `Native Phone App` (in React Native) and `Express REST API` with auth based on `JWT`. I have 7 day expiration set.

Am I supposed to refresh (generate new and throw old) token every time user 'cold' open app (for example after 2 days of inactivity)?

Or just use the old one and refresh it like 1 day before or ask for login combo again.

So my questions are: Refresh it? And if yes, when?

Comment: The payload of a JWT can contain timely information about issued date, expiration date, etc. Refreshing at token is common and may occur for reasons other than time-sensitive information. For example, if a user updates their email address, they may take the opportuniry to refresh their token because an aspect of their account has changed. As far as refreshing it based on time, it's really up to you to decide when you'd like to refresh it. It can be if it's going to expire in a day, 1 hour, 5 minutes. Also, keep in mind expired tokens should not be refreshed and should instead prompt re-login.

Comment: I took about 15 seconds to write this. I've been working with JWT for years. I guess I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use Refresh token and Access token, it's very simple, every Access token (your current JWT) has 7 or 3 days to expiration, and your Refresh token have not expiration time, client will send access token after expiration time and got 401 Unauthorized error, your client have request to refresh token route and get a new access token that has 7 days of expiration time. it's like to user login with another token instead Username and Password.

[Access and Refresh tokens in NodeJS](https://solidgeargroup.com/refresh-token-with-jwt-authentication-node-js/)